# Absolute positioning of axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib I tried to position the axes of a figure such that the axes rectangle has its
lower left corner at (100, 100) and its upper right corner at (400, 400),
assuming the unit of the given coordinates is point (pt).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['ps.papersize'] = 'a4'

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.27, 11.69))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot([1,3,2])

mybbox = ax.get_position()
mybbox.x0, mybbox.y0 = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform((100, 100))
mybbox.x1, mybbox.y1 = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform((400, 400))
ax.set_position(mybbox)

print(fig.transFigure.transform(ax.get_position()))

plt.savefig('foo.ps')
```

But the created postscript file yields that the axes' corners are actually
at (72,72) and (288,288):

```
72 72 m
288 72 l
288 288 l
72 288 l
cl
```

Thus all coordinates are off target by a constant factor of 0.72.
Did I do something wrong by applying the `transFigure` transformation
to calculate the absolute position of the axes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 pixel are 0.72 points. `fig.transFigure.inverted()` transforms from display space, which uses pixels, not points. 
To be precise you would also need to take the figure dpi into account (which is dpi=100 by default). So using

```
ppd = 72./fig.dpi  # points per dot
mybbox = ax.get_position()
mybbox.x0, mybbox.y0 = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform((100/ppd, 100/ppd))
mybbox.x1, mybbox.y1 = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform((400/ppd, 400/ppd))
ax.set_position(mybbox)
```

should result in

```
gsave
100 100 m
400 100 l
400 400 l
100 400 l
cl
```

in the post script file.

Comment: I see. Coordinates have to be specified as **number of pixels** and not as **length in points**. Thank you.